# Не работает overflow:scroll в Android 2.2 и 2.3

Tags: android, javascript, прокрутка, css

Есть блок c фиксированной высотой, с контентом внутри. Внизу кнопка, которая подгружает еще контент. При этом должен появиться скроллбар и контент должен прокручиваться (overflow:scroll). На мобильных устройствах скроллбар не появляется, но это понятно почему(это было бы некрасиво с точки зрения UI). Прокрутка все равно работает везде, за исключением Андроида 2 и скорее всего 3.
Судя по всему это баг самой системы. Вопрос в том, как заставить контент прокручиваться. Прокрутка работает в iOS прекрасно, и на Android 4 все ок.
Пробовал использовать iscroll.js
Но что-то не работает. Есть ли у кого опыт в этом вопросе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS свойства `overflow:scroll, overflow:auto` не поддерживаются стоковым браузером Webkit. Описание бага висит на сайте Google - [фтыкать сюда](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2911). Согласно отчетам наблюдается с 1.5 до 2.3

P.S. На iPhone говорят то же самое, что неудивительно поскольку обе оси юзают один и тот же браузер [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)

Comment: Добавлю, что на версиях до 2.3 это решается с помощью javascript'a, со всеми вытекающими тормозами.